# File not found while parsing a json file in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I have a problem in a Xamarin.Forms application that I am developing. I need to read the content of a `.json` file, to be showed in a `CarouselView`. I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` library to parse the file.

However, it continously gives to me an error that it cannot find the file. The `c#` code is as follows:

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using PalazzoVecchioDemo.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace PalazzoVecchioDemo.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class VisitChoice : ContentPage
    {
        private const string _json = "rooms.json";

        public ObservableCollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Room>();

        public VisitChoice()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //necessary to do data binding to elements present in this page
            //(in particular to the observable collection of rooms)
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string previousFolder = Path.Combine(path, @"..\");
            string jsonPath = Path.Combine(path, _json);

            var rooms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Room[]>(File.ReadAllText(_json));

            Rooms.Clear();

            foreach(var room in rooms)
            {
                Rooms.Add(room);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `.xaml` code is as follows (I put only the significant part of it:

```xml
!-- Carousel view with all the contents -->
        <CarouselView Grid.Row="1" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms}" 
                      Loop="False">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame HasShadow="True" 
                               BorderColor="DarkGray" 
                               CornerRadius="5" 
                               Margin="20" 
                               HeightRequest="300" 
                               HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                       FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                       FontSize="Large" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="True"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

The project structure is as follows; I am writing the `VisitChoice` page (inside the `Views` folder) and the file I want to read is `rooms.json`.

[image: project structure]

Anyone could please help me?

Comment: you can't embed files in a library project like that.  You can embed them in the app's platform projects, or you can include it as an embedded resource in the library

Comment: Could you please explain me how to do it?

Comment: I offered two options, which one?  Using an embedded resource in a .NET application is well documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the json file in Xamarin.Forms project as `Embedded resource`, you could use the code below to read and deserialize.

**1. Get the matched classes for the json data.**

Copy your json string. Click Edit> Paste Special> Paste JSON As
Classes. After that, you could get the classes you want.

**2. Use the code below to read the `Embedded resource`json file and deserialize.**

```
 string _json = "rooms.json";
        Room ObjList = new Room();


        var assembly = typeof(Page20).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{_json}");
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            ObjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Room>(jsonString);
        }
```

Comment: It does not work for me: the stream variable returns null. Where should I put the json file? Inside the same folder of the .cs file?

Comment: The same location you showed in the screenshot. And set the Build Action of the json file as `Embedded resource`. Right click the json file> Properties> Build Action.

Comment: `Page20` in my code is the class name of the contentpage. You need to use you own.

Comment: I know, I used the class name of my contentPage. And I already set the Build Action of the json file as Embedded Resource. However, I stil have the stream variable that returns null

Comment: Ok I have solved the issue: I was writing in a wrong way ```Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{_json}")```. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following points:

- in Visual Studio, it's possible to copy a file in the output folder. Please check the property windows when you click on the JSON file. Maybe it will not copy to the bin folder where your EXE or code is running.
- Before you are starting with DeserializeObject, I would check the path if the file really exists. File. Exists() Method.
- When you access the file, check if you are in the right folder. Maybe your file is in another subfolder, and you are one folder above.
- For accessing, use total paths to avoid issues.

Comment: this is fine advice for a desktop app, but does not really apply to a mobile app

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to avoid embed files in the way that you're doing. For JSON, I recommend you to create the file while your app is running, even if it will create just one time.

For that, you can:

- Use, for example, `App.xaml.cs` to process your JSON (it will be one of the first classes to your project run). You can store your JSON (if it's static, seeing that you're trying to embed it) in a [resx file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows) to access the strings.
- Creating and updating a JSON file:

```
        public void SaveJSON(string jsonText) 
        {
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "myJson.json"), jsonText);
        }
```

- Get your JSON file to use it:

```
        public string GetJSON()
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "myJson.json");
            string json = (File.Exists(path)) ? File.ReadAllText(path) : "";
            return json;
        }
```

If you don't want to create `resx file`, you can just, in your App.xaml.cs, pass for one time `SaveJSON("")` to create your JSON document.